# jupyter prints too many outputs even when I didn't print

Tags: python, jupyter

Recently Jupyter (both Notebook and Lab) started to print anything as if I am executing each line separately. It used to print out the output of the very last line of the execution, but now it prints everything as shown below.

[image]

I can suppress this by doing, e.g., `_ = axs[0].plot(~~~)`, but putting semicolon at the end of each line does not help. I have reinstalled Anaconda but nothing changed.

I am using macOS 10.14.6 on MBP 2018 15", Python 3.8 (basically everything that the current Anaconda installs, without any additional installation) on MS Edge 87.0.664.47.

**EDIT:**
More precisely, any line of code which has a return value that is **not** assigned to a variable is always **printed**. Previously, each line was "printed" only when it is the very last line of the code. This strange behavior happens regardless of packages, such as numpy or pandas:
[image]

(FYI, copiable text:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def add_with_return(arr):
    arr += 1
    return arr

a = np.arange(10)
b = pd.DataFrame(dict(value=a))
a, b
add_with_return(a)
c = np.linspace(0, 1)
```

)

**EDIT2**:

Versions of packages I used

```
$ jupyter --version
jupyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : 6.1.4
qtconsole        : 4.7.7
ipython          : 7.19.0
ipykernel        : 5.3.4
jupyter client   : 6.1.7
jupyter lab      : 2.2.6
nbconvert        : 6.0.7
ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
nbformat         : 5.0.8
traitlets        : 5.0.5
```

**EDIT 3:**

I think I finally found a workaround:
**Put `;` at the end of *the last line of the code cell***.

Example: **add a dummy line `None;` at the end of the cell** to silence all the unwanted prints.

[image]

But once you have any line of code which does not have `;` at the end of it at the last line of the code cell, it prints everything again (whether or not you have `;` at the end of the other lines)

I want to hear if there is any better solution for this. (Who would ever want to put semicolon all the time...?)

Comment: Is this only in Matplotlib or also other modules like Pandas?

Comment: @RuthgerRighart It happens to any package, so I guess it's not a problem of matplotlib (but likely it is the most problematic for matplotlib as it is frequently used without assigning the output to a variable). I have just updated (edited) the question to address your comment.

Comment: Can you share your visualization code with dummy data to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel Any simple lines could reproduce it. ```fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1);
ax.plot([10], [10]);
ax.set_xlabel("test")``` prints ```[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x123291bb0>]
Text(0.5, 0, 'test')``` and the Axes object. Note that, as I added in the EDIT3 of the main body, I can silence the notebook by adding ``;`` to the last line or add a dummy line such as ``None;``.

Comment: It works, I have added the image on my comments. As I mentioned, find the line that is printing and place `;` to mute the output. If that does not work, then there are other settings in play.

Answer (score 5):

In IPython, there is an option `InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity` that you can set to 'all', 'last', 'last_expr', 'none', or 'last_expr_or_assign'. The default setting is 'last_expr'. Find more information in the IPython documentation [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/terminal.html).

When I type the following in a Jupyter cell, to imitate your situation.

```
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = 'all'
```

The code you provided:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def add_with_return(arr):
    arr += 1
    return arr

a = np.arange(10)
b = pd.DataFrame(dict(value=a))
a, b
add_with_return(a)
c = np.linspace(0, 1)
```

It gives the following output:

```
(array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
    value
 0      0
 1      1
 2      2
 3      3
 4      4
 5      5
 6      6
 7      7
 8      8
 9      9)

 array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

Finally using the following brings it back to the previous state.

```
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = 'last_expr'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I think this should work. Following the docs, I added ``c.InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = 'last_expr'`` to the file ``~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py``, but nothing changed. Could you help me updating the settings?

Answer (score 1):

The semicolon should work if placed on correct level.

Make sure `;` is set at last **top level** in multiple layers e.g.
`fig, axes = plt.subplots(2);`

You can then add `;` at the end of your code lines that generate unwanted outputs  to mute them. E.g: `ABC.plot(XYZ);`

**Updates**: Mute `;` worked even when I placed only on the last line. If it does not, then the issue comes somewhere else.

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned in the original question, putting semicolon (I even tried to put it at the end of every single line of my code) did nothing.

Comment: Mmh that is strange. I cannot reproduce it on my side. `;` works. Can you share your dummy sample of your code? I would like to reproduce what you have.